# Select n columns, with the rest of line added to the end of the last column, using read_csv()

Tags: python, pandas, regex, csv

I am using Pandas to read with `read_csv()` a file with fields separated by spaces. There is a fixed number of columns, but a few lines do not follow the pattern.

The solution I used so far is to add `on_bad_lines='warn'` which skips them and informs me that there is a faulty line.

This was OK while there were a few lines I could look at separately. Unfortunately, the number of such lines increased.

The solution I would be fine with would be to load only 10 columns: 9 that are always fine (and have predictable names), and the 10th one that would have the rest of the line as one column (called 'everything else').

I was looking back and forth at the [documentation for `read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) but I could not find the right parameter. Is there a way to limit the number of columns to read in (including a last column with the rest of the line)?

To put some context: the kind of file I have

```
aaax bbb ccc ddd
mmmxxx nnn ooo ppp sjkhdkjsh skdjhsksdkskjdh  ksjh sdkjsdh  ksjdh
fffxx ggg hhh iii
```

I would like retrieve four columns on each line, the fourth column would be (for each line)

```
ddd
ppp sjkhdkjsh skdjhsksdkskjdh  ksjh sdkjsdh  ksjdh
iii
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a limited number of columns plus the rest of line as a string into a Pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64475519/how-to-read-a-limited-number-of-columns-plus-the-rest-of-line-as-a-string-into-a)

Comment: does your actual data have spaces in it? What is the raw format you are taking it from?

Answer (score 1):

My humble approach:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = """aaax bbb ccc ddd
mmmxxx nnn ooo ppp sjkhdkjsh skdjhsksdkskjdh  ksjh sdkjsdh  ksjdh
fffxx ggg hhh iii
"""
n = 3
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep="\s+", header=None, usecols = range(n))
df['last'] = pd.Series(data.splitlines()).str.split(n = n).str[-1]
```

Output:

```
        0    1    2                                               last
0    aaax  bbb  ccc                                                ddd
1  mmmxxx  nnn  ooo  ppp sjkhdkjsh skdjhsksdkskjdh  ksjh sdkjsdh  k...
2   fffxx  ggg  hhh                                                iii
```

Comment: I was wondering if not to put a note in my question about the fact that I do not want to select the columns I want to use, but ultimately decided against for fear of confusion :) I did try to use `usecols` but this requires me to cut at some point, without having the rest of the line as the last column. Or at least this is how I understand it (I am brand new to Pandas)

Comment: Yes, I clarified that in the question right now

Comment: Thanks for changing the title, it is much better now

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can try setting a *regex* as a separator in [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) :

```
N = 4 # Which col ? Fourth.

pat = r"{}(.+)".format("(?:\S+)\s+"*(N-1))

col = pd.read_csv("file.txt", sep=pat, header=None, engine="python")[1]
```

> Demo : [[*Regex*](https://regex101.com/r/LgJGZe/3)]

Output :

```
print(col)

0                                                   ddd
1    ppp sjkhdkjsh skdjhsksdkskjdh  ksjh sdkjsdh  ksjdh
2                                                   iii
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, which reads the CSV file into a single-column dataframe (therefore, using `\t+` as a separator that does not exist in the text file) and then splits the single columns into 4 columns.

```
data = """aaax bbb ccc ddd
mmmxxx nnn ooo ppp sjkhdkjsh skdjhsksdkskjdh  ksjh sdkjsdh  ksjdh
fffxx ggg hhh iii
"""

N = 3

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\t+', header=None, engine='python')
df[0].str.split(n=N, expand=True)
```

Output:

```
        0    1    2                                                  3
0    aaax  bbb  ccc                                                ddd
1  mmmxxx  nnn  ooo  ppp sjkhdkjsh skdjhsksdkskjdh  ksjh sdkjsdh  k...
2   fffxx  ggg  hhh                                                iii
```